# Is there a way to reject the dragging of a TListView item in Automatic drag mode, before it starts?

Tags: listview, delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-2009

This is simple. I want to have a chance to refuse the beginning of dragging (before it happens) if I think that a particular item is not qualified for dragging. It is possible ?

I tried to implement my own dragging system but there are some cases when it is not working properly:

```
procedure TNewListView.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var StartIt: Boolean;
    DragIndex: Integer;
begin
 if (ssLeft in Shift) and not Dragging then begin
  DragIndex:= GetItemIndexAt(X, Y);
  if (DragIndex >= 0) and IsIndexSelected(DragIndex) then begin
   StartIt:= False;
   if Assigned(FOnBeforeDrag) then FOnBeforeDrag(Self, DragIndex, StartIt);
   if StartIt then BeginAutoDrag;
  end;
 end;
 inherited;
end;
```

Comment: You can `CancelDrag` e.g. from the `OnStartDrag` event, but in this case I would consider using manual mode (as you'll be cancelling operation which did not need to start in the first place).

Comment: But I can't find `CancelDrag` in ListView methods...

Comment: It's a standalone procedure from `Controls` module.

Comment: Wow ! It's exactly what I was needed ! :) Thanks. You can post it as an answer. But I don't understand what you ar saying about manual mode... I tested it with automatic mode and it works. In the manual mode, there is no point to cancel it, because you can choose not to start it from the very beginning. The automatic mode was the problem...

Comment: You could be listening for the `LVN_BEGINDRAG` notification and `BeginDrag` by yourself (but only if the selected items meet your conditions).

Comment: That will be a good way to do it, but It seems that `BeginDrag` has a bug: sometimes the image of the item being dragged is white on black and other times is black on white, randomly...

Comment: But it is the same `BeginDrag` called from the `WMLButtonDown` method for automatic mode. I cannot see any difference (on Windows 7). I can see always same drag image there (which is created only for a single item being dragged).

Comment: I don't know what to say... but this is happening to me... Anyway, canceling the dragg operation in OnStartDrag works fine.